# add top item to photo gallery touchTouch

Tags: jquery-mobile, photo

Hi i am new jquery mobile. I need to add photo gallery to my apps. After goggling i decide use this plugin to my apps
http://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/

So here is my question I need to dynamic add item to first photo of the photo gallery.
Please c my code below

mobile.html

```
 <div class="thumbs" id="imageList">
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_m.jpg)" title="Lion Rock"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_m.jpg)" title="Holsten Gate"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_m.jpg)" title="Blue Hour"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_m.jpg)" title="Waikato Landscape"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_m.jpg)" title="Tauranga Bridge"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_m.jpg)" title="East Coast"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_m.jpg)" title="Cathedral Cove"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_m.jpg)" title="The Pond"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_m.jpg)" title="Good Night"></a>
                </div>

                <p id="credit">

                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6754656011/">Lion Rock</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6895252645/">Holsten Gate</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6943277737/">Blue Hour</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/7000951429/">Waikato Landscape</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/7051537899/">Tauranga Bridge</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6951148260/">East Coast</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6930112984/">Cathedral Cove</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6886626710/">The Pond</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6683299491/">Good Night</a>
                </p>
```

addtopitem.js

```
  $("#imageList").prepend("<a href=\"http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_z.jpg\" style=\"background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_m.jpg)\" title=\"1234\" class=\"ui-link\"></a>");

        $("#credit").prepend("<a ihref=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6754656011/\"  class=\"ui-link\">Lion Rock</a>");



        $('#thumbs a').touchTouch();
```

I am able to add item to top of the photo gallery. But when click the image it seem like no function at all. Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code.

First rule of working with 3rd party plugins is "change things only if it's allowed or if you know what are you doing".

You have incorrectly renamed id to class in this div container:

```
<div class="thumbs" id="imageList">
```

It should be:

```
<div id="thumbs imageList">
```

This plugin is hard coded to work with <div> **#imageList** container.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/nYbUL/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>A Touch Optimized Gallery | Tutorialzine Freebie</title>

        <!-- Make the page take the full width of the device-->
        <meta name="viewport"  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- The stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/assets/css/styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/assets/touchTouch/touchTouch.css" />

        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script" />

        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <body>     
        <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Gallery example
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <a data-role="button" id="add-thumbnail">Add another thumbnail</a>
                <div id="thumbs">
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_m.jpg)" title="Lion Rock"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6895252645_45f5dfffaa_m.jpg)" title="Holsten Gate"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7183/6943277737_21b521659c_m.jpg)" title="Blue Hour"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7047/7000951429_5eae078a62_m.jpg)" title="Waikato Landscape"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5346/7051537899_efc7a44830_m.jpg)" title="Tauranga Bridge"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7268/6951148260_440661b4d1_m.jpg)" title="East Coast"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7259/6930112984_5fcc076288_m.jpg)" title="Cathedral Cove"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7276/6886626710_047cd03acb_m.jpg)" title="The Pond"></a>
                    <a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_z.jpg" style="background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7020/6683299491_f2b5f6aa8b_m.jpg)" title="Good Night"></a>
                </div>

                <p id="credit">
                    Photos: 
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6754656011/">Lion Rock</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6895252645/">Holsten Gate</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6943277737/">Blue Hour</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/7000951429/">Waikato Landscape</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/7051537899/">Tauranga Bridge</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6951148260/">East Coast</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6930112984/">Cathedral Cove</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6886626710/">The Pond</a>
                    <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6683299491/">Good Night</a>
                </p>
            </div>                  
        </div>              

        <!-- JavaScript includes - jQuery, turn.js and our own script.js -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>  
        <script src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/assets/touchTouch/touchTouch.jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery/assets/js/script.js"></script>    
        <script>
        $(document).on('pageshow', '#index', function(){ 
            $(document).on('click', '#add-thumbnail', function(){       
                $("#thumbs").prepend("<a href=\"http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_z.jpg\" style=\"background-image:url(http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7013/6754656011_3de2cc73a2_m.jpg)\" title=\"1234\" class=\"ui-link\"></a>");
                $("#credit").prepend("<a ihref=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/zanthia/6754656011/\"  class=\"ui-link\">Lion Rock</a>");
            });
            ('#thumbs a').touchTouch();
        });
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```